# Adding new static scopes to existing Azure AD app registration

Tags: azure-active-directory

My AD tenant has user consent disabled, i.e., all permissions added to AD app registration need an admin consent.
For an application using static permissions/scopes (v1.0 OAuth/OpenId endpoint), is it possible to add new permissions such that until the admin consent is granted, users can continue using features which require only the existing consented scopes?
[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#incremental-and-dynamic-consent) say: *"The app needs to know all of the resources it would ever access ahead of time. It was difficult to create apps that could access an arbitrary number of resources."* Does it mean that for my scenario, all users need to wait for admin consent before they can access the app?

I receive the below error when a user tries logging in to the app using the [Open ID Connect flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code). For reference, my login URL is similar to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=b8ad6a99-cd23-40a6-a1b4-1184af990aa2&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F&state=13ccfb84-cfd1-4cb0-bfe3-bb2c227e19f7&client-request-id=4d76947a-0000-48af-aeff-7bc2d5e40000&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.17&nonce=ef1caa16-d3fe-4523-a9c9-000000000000

[image: Error screenshot link]

[image: AD app registration screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to add new permissions such that until the admin consent is granted, users can continue using features which require only the existing consented scopes?

Yes, you can. 
When the admin consent the API permission of an AD App(`App registration`), the permissions essentially will be given to the service principal(`Enterprise application`) in your AAD tenant. Actually if you use the AD App in your tenant, the permissions are essentially from the service principal.

You could refer to the screenshot below, there are four permissions, the two permission has been granted.

[image]

Navigate to the `Overview`, click the option `Manage application in local directory`.

[image]

Then in the `Permissions`, you will find the two permissions which have been consent.

[image]

Comment: updated the question with a screenshot of the error I receive after I add a new scope to the app. Since user consent is disabled, there is no way for the user to proceed.

Comment: @SumitTalesara Could you show the screenshot of the API permissions in your AD App?

Comment: @SumitTalesara The new permission and the old ones are not in the same API, you can just get the token for only one resource, e.g. microsoft graph or your own API. So if you use the new resource in your request, it needs the admin consent, otherwise you will get the error.

Comment: Since I am using v1.0 OAuth endpoint, it doesn't allow incremental consent. Going by the error, it seems the admin consent needs to be granted for all scopes at once.

Comment: @SumitTalesara Are you using the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code)? Could the user login when you just use the `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com`? If he , it means the old permission takes effect.

Comment: @SumitTalesara It is the same logic, in conclusion, if you are using the resource with an API, at least one permission needs to be consent, then when you add new permission in this API without consent, the old permission will also work. But if you add a new API, the resource has been changed, it will not work.

Comment: @SumitTalesara Could you get that? That means you can just get the token for one resource at one time, in your screenshot, there are three different APIs(resources). So if you just specify the resource with the new one, the old permissions in other APIs will not work.

Comment: Sorry, I am using the [Open ID connect flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code). The redirect URL does not specify any resource. It is of this form:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token
&client_id=7144e8cb
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F
&state=13ccfb84-cfd1-4cb0-bfe3-bb2c227e19f7
&client-request-id=4d76947a-0000-48af-aeff-7bc2d5e40000
&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.17
&nonce=ef1caa16-d3fe-4523-a9c9-000000000000

Comment: @SumitTalesara You missed the `scope` , `response_mode`, `resource`, just try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code#get-access-tokens), modify `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com`.

Comment: @SumitTalesara Once you login in, it means the permission `User.Read` of Microsoft Graph works.

Comment: @SumitTalesara Hi, any other concern? if not, please accept it as answer, thank you very much.:-)

Comment: Adding the required resource fixed the issue. Thanks! The issue was due to a missing scope in the AD app.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the new scopes, the app will keep working, but it will only be able to access the old scopes until the admin consents to the new scopes.

Thanks!
Alex Simons